# Error en la creación de una transacción en SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, transacciones

Estoy tratando de implementar transacciones en un procedimiento almacenado, en el cual solo obtiene el último registro de una tabla, este número lo pasa como parámetro de salida.

Pero estoy generando el siguiente error:

> El recuento de transacciones después de EXECUTE indica un número no coincidente de instrucciones BEGIN y COMMIT. Recuento anterior = 0, recuento actual = 1.

Soy nuevo implementando transacciones, pero en este procedimiento almacenado no requiero de controlar ningun `rollback`, solamente hacer un transaccion simple.

Este es el código de mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ultIdCamp(@id int output)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT @id = MAX(id_campana) FROM campana;
    IF (@id IS NULL)
        BEGIN
        SET @id = 1;
        RETURN @id;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @id = @id + 1;
        RETURN @id;
        END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Este es el código de mi método escrito en C#:

```
public void obtenUltimoRegistro()
        {
            cnn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = store_procedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "ultIdCamp";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                id = (int)cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value;
                label3.Text = "" + id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
                cnn.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Al encerrar la declaración del objeto Connection entre un bloque Using ... End Using, nos estaremos asegurando de cerrar la conexión y de destruir los recursos utilizados por el objeto, al finalizar dicho bloque (cuando se ejecute End Using).

Comment: Con ésto no tenemos que estar pendientes de llamar al método Close (para cerrar la conexión), ni tampoco al método Dispose (para destruir el objeto), por tanto, no es necesario disponer de un procedimiento externo para tales menesteres.

Comment: `using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
            {
                ....
            }`

Comment: Y por ultimo `Parameters.Add` esta absoleto deberías usar `AddWithValue` https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PedroÁvila bueno...no todo el mundo está muy de acuerdo con usar `AddWithValue`. Lee [esto](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) (en ingles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar, no había entendido que por cada caso debe de existir ya sea un `COMMIT` o un `ROLLBACK`. En este caso en el `IF...ELSE`, debe de haber un `COMMIT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ultIdCamp(@id int output)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT @id = MAX(id_campana) FROM campana;
IF (@id IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    SET @id = 1;
    COMMIT TRAN
    RETURN @id;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SET @id = @id + 1;
    COMMIT TRAN
    RETURN @id;
    END
END
```

Comment: Abrir una transacción antes de una SELECT y cerrarla después no tiene sentido/utilidad. En SQL Server por defecto una transacción solo bloquea cuando hay modificación de datos. Además la propia SELECT tiene "una transacción implicita" que te garantiza que desde que se empieza a hacer la SELECT hasta que se acaba no ha habido modificación en los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco la finalidad del código, pero yo no usaría transacciones para un proceso tan sencillo. Si prescindes de ellas puedes obtener el mismo resultado ya que las consultas son transaccionales.

Yo cambiaría el código por esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ultIdCamp(@id int output)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    SELECT @id = 1 + ISNULL(MAX(id_campana), 0) FROM campana;    
    RETURN @id;
END
```

Incluso iría más allá y para calcular un contador usaría un campo IDENTITY.

Espero haber ayudado,